# Javascript unable to Show/hide Dom Element (on Pannellum example)

Tags: javascript, dom, pannellum

i have a problem when i try to hide/show an element in the DOM using the javascript call document.getElementById(elemId).style.visibility = visible/hidden.

This is a very strange behaviour , when i get the DOM element by id and set the visibility to visible, in the console i can see that the inline style have been modified but the element on the screen is still hidden.

I'll link a fiddle example of my problem, hope someone can help

This is the function i'm using to hide/show DOM elements

```
function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
  if (typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    document.getElementById(elmId).style.visibility = value;
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

Anyway even the direct call `document.getElementById('2').style.visibility = 'visible'` is not working

PS What i'm trying to achieve is to show the span over the exclamation mark that is, for css default, hidden

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxu2q3pu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `updateHtml` the element has not been created yet.

**For testing** added the updateHtml inside a timeout call after 1s and it works.

```
setTimeout(() => updateHTML("8", "visible"), 1000);
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxu2q3pu/42/)

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY! Thanks a lot for the hint

Comment: Maanoo i want to show you this other fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/boLtzbvq/ is the same example as before but some elements are generated dynamically. This time your solution is not working :( Have you some hints to spare? :)

Comment: @Nic added a correct listener instaed of a timeout and generated the spots first and then added them to the config https://jsfiddle.net/boLtzbvq/30/ (sorry for the delay)

Comment: MaanooAk you have been faster than light and AGAIN you solved my problem. Many many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your fiddle, but the `id` that you mentioned to the following code does not exist:

```
updateHTML("8", "visible");
```

Into your update function you do this ...

```
function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elmId); // <- this line
  if (typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    document.getElementById(elmId).style.visibility = value;
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

But you get the id of unexisting element.

Other [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])` and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits `([0-9])`, hyphens ("`-`"),
>   underscores ("`_`"), colons ("`:`"), and periods ("`.`").

Comment: As you can see https://ibb.co/mGvsRc the span element id exists. Anyway i'll try to change id and name tokens as you suggested to see if something will change :)

Comment: Try to change the id and go on! ;)